# android onClick Does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

The code worked fine in other layout, but in others not..

layout XML:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="register"
        android:id="@+id/welcome_register"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:onClick="register_Click" />
```

Activity:

```
package il.co.smartchip.hobby;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    public void start_login(View view) {
        //TODO log in
    }

    public void register_Click(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I tried several things without success. Do you have any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Is your button in the correct layout file?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

Comment: are there fragments involved?

Comment: I tried your way and my answer and both working good , i think @prudhvi is right

Comment: @MilosLulic it worked :D can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need `Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);`.

`LoginActivity.this` points to the instance of the Activity you are currently in and you using it when you work with dynamic inner class like in your case.

`this` is for your current Object.

Im not so good teacher, hope you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

> Delete onclick on xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="register"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_register"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />
```

> Init your button like that

```
package il.co.smartchip.hobby;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button myButton;
private Activity thisActivity=this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.welcome_register);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Suggesting a different way to solve the problem is not the answer, see what's wrong with the OP's implementation.

Comment: I know but i just think maybe this way will help him. Sorry

Comment: And in case of two buttons?

Comment: What you mean "in case of two buttons" , you want to create and assign on click to both ?

Comment: Two different buttons. each action is different.

Comment: You can create another button with different android:id value. Init your button like findViewById line. And add onclick listener method to it. My answer is general , you can add another buttons,imageButtons, imageViews etc. Just try , you will enjoy :)

Comment: Yes you right. Theese are coding habits. You can assign onClick to a view via xml or java code . Also you can use Dagger or ButterKnife too. Check this link : http://www.thekeyconsultant.com/2013/09/5-reasons-you-should-use-butterknife.html